# I need to use the PDF.Convert.ToXod but this exception comes

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, pdftron

I need to use the **pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToXod** but this exception comes:

Message: An error occurred while converting the file.Detailed error:Error creating a new Word application instance.Log: Start check system account.  Session ID is: 0.  Done checking system account.  Start checking registry. Registry check done.  Creating a Word application instance. Conditional expression: false Filename   : Convert.cpp Function   : trn::PDF::Convert::ToPdf Linenumber : 1612

This function is called in an mvc website running on application pool in IIS.
The user for application pool is administrator.

**i notice when i call this method from WebAPI function it throws this error**, howerver if the same method is called from browser with a validated user the code works and also subsequent request to the api also start working.

the api function is without user identity [AllowAnonymous].

Please kindly help me find a reason so i can fix it. Its because i cant manually go and call this from browser every time application pool restarts the website, i want that if api calls this first , then it be successfully done , i also tried to call **PDFNet.Initialize** function at **global.asax** , it does nothing different.

Comment: What kind of Office subscription do you have? Is it an Office 365 subscription?

Answer (score 0):

The following links will probably help you.

https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/faq_files/Converting_Documents_in_Windows_Service_or_ASP.NET_Application_using_PDFNet.pdf

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pdfnet-webviewer/F5SdHgb__1w/PSjoj22qCwAJ

Or try the test project to validate your IIS setup.

https://www.pdftron.com/ID-zJWLuhTffd3c/support/PDFNet_IIS_Word_ToXod_Test2013.7z